# Rates of doing work

Tags: calculus

When they work together, it takes Tom Sawyer and huckleberry Finn 8 hours to paint a fence. If Tom can paint a fence by himself an hour faster than Huckleberry Finn can, how long does Tom Sawyer take to paint 3 fences by himself? Assume that Tom Sawyer works a maximum of 8 hours per day.

Comment: I couldn't solve this question that's why I need some help with it. I'm trying to apply for a tutor assistant position and my math is not that good. So I'm just trying to do everything to soak up math concepts and knowledge for the position. Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Let Tom Sawyer complete the work in $T$ hours and Huckleberry Finn complete the work in $H$ hours.

Then ,

$$\frac1T + \frac1H = \frac18$$

Also $T +1 = H$

$$\frac1T + \frac1{T+1} = \frac18$$

$$T^2 -15T -8 = 0$$

Can you continue this from here??

Comment: T=H-1, since Tom is faster than Huck

Comment: @MatthewDaly Thanks for pointing out !

Comment: I got the answer as 5days 6hours and 33 minutes. Is that correct?